# copy linked materials nodes to local material

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

***DISCLAIMER:*** I rewrite my post upon the latest success to not flood my own post with already solved parts so I left only the part that really is still not working...

*PROBLEM:* 
I need to replace all nodes of one material with all nodes of another linked material from another external .blend file via script.

**I ALREADY HAVE ALMOST COMPLETELY WORKING SCRIPT NOW ALL MADE BY MYSELF AT LEAST**, except the last thing: copying links between nodes...

Does anyone know how exactly write those two parameters, please?

I am using Blender v2.70.5

**P.S.: I need strictly SCRIPT BASED ANSWERS ONLY**...I know how to do it manually, of course

Comment: The answer may be more complex than you hope. There is a rather large contrib addon called [online_material_library](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/online_mat_lib/__init__.py) that exports materials to xml and imports them. There is also [a patch](https://developer.blender.org/T37908) that updates it for the new group api as well as support for nested groups. Maybe you could use that or adapt it to bypass the xml file step.

Comment: @sambler: did you noticed I edited my post stating I WAS ABLE TO DO IT except the last part of simple copying links from nodes? ;) So now I think it can be quite easily done like this I just still didn't figured out how to extract just the values itself from every link in node.links, or even better said: I am able to obtain every link values but when I try to apply it to nodes it says there is problem with type of value

Comment: @admins: please flag this post as [SOLVED] as I come to solution myself as described above...thanx ;)

Comment: @bublible Feel free to put your script in an answer below and accept it. [Answering your own question is in fact encouraged](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), and to be "solved" a question needs an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally made it myself again after several hours of playing with the code (see I am actually FLASH ActionScript2 guy so it took me like 2 weeks to understand syntax of Python, its objects etc. and get used to it but now I have fully working script!!!).

**The right solution is this:**

```
# ...some quite long code here and now:
for r in _mNews.links: 
    _mOld.links.new(_mOld.nodes[r.from_node.name].outputs[r.from_socket.name], _mOld.nodes[r.to_node.name].inputs[r.to_socket.name])
```